Prisma "include" query
I have the following code:
const responses = await prismaClient.submission.findMany({
  where: {
    task_id: Number(taskId)
  },
  include: {
    option: true
  }
})

What is the role of the include property?
I am guessing it is used to map two of the models while querying, but at the same time, I have defined the relation.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations#retrieve-a-record-and-include-related-records Retrieve a record and include related records ... in your scenario option is expected to be an association called option in the submission model
